# crontab centos wordpress wp-load

Tags: wordpress, cron

I am using on centos server crontab

```
* * * * * php -q /var/www/domain.com/public_html/script.php
```

script.php contents:

```
<?php 
require_once( '/var/www/domain.com/public_html/wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE id = 70");
$fn = "/var/www/domain.com/public_html/file.txt";
$file = fopen($fn, "a+");
fwrite($file, $results."\n");
fclose($file);
?>
```

When I go directly to: http://www.domain.com/script.php it executes fine and writes to file, when crontab is want to execute i didnt get writen result from db to file.txt... What is the problem ? it seem wont to load wp-load.php? any ideas ?

Crontab is working, when I comment wp-load.php it writes to file...

Answer (score 0):

Without insight in your system, this might be related to permissions. What user runs this via the web interface, and what user runs this via `cron`?

In any case, you should put error checking in your PHP script:

```
$file = fopen($fn, "a+");
if (! $file)
    print("Oops, cannot open $file\n");
```

See e.g. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp) for an example of error reporting in such things.

Comment: Yes but this is problem in wp-load.php, as I said when I comment this line it writes to txt file.

Comment: OK, different approach, try invoking it from crontab using `curl`, as in `* * * * * curl http://localhost/where/ever/wp-load.php`, that way you bypass webuser or non-webuser issues? BTW I don't understand what you mean with "when I comment this line". Which line? Also: check the crontab user's mail, crontab will happily dump all output there.

Comment: I mean about comment line where requires wp-load.php file. I tried with curl and it worked like a charm!!! thank you! Did i need to delete after curl ? because many files will be in server ? or not ?

Comment: The way this is wired, is that file `/var/www/domain.com/public_html/file.txt` is appended to. So you won't have many files, but the file will grow because it's opened in append-mode `a+`. You might want to periodically remove it, or shorten it.
Plus, oops, my above comment says `curl ...wp-load.php`. Should of course be `script.php`.

Comment: And maybe re-verify that you have the right `curl` files. Note that the commandline `curl` may be configured differently than the PHP module..

Comment: Yes the text file is for testing purposes. Thank you for Help!